# Notepad++ regex - howto replace all underscores, which follow a = sign?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have expressions with underscores, which follow the following rule.

```
alpha_num_1=alpha_num_1
alpha_num_2=alpha_num_2
....
```

In the middle there are allways = signs.
I would like to replace underscores, right to the = sign.

```
alpha_num_1=alpha num 1
alpha_num_2=alpha num 2
....
```

Is it possible using regex replacement in Notepad++ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a find of:

```
(=[A-Za-z]*)_
```

And replace it with:

```
$1
```

[Note: there is a space after the `$1`]

Be sure to check the 'Regular expression' mode, and click replace all.

Sometimes, you need to select all first (when your cursor is at the end and you have 'Find Down' checked for instance)

I'm assuming there are only alphabets between the equal sign and the underscore you want to remove.

Comment: Doesn't this just replace the first underscore? The second one next to the number is not replaced.

Comment: @FrancisGagnon Huh, I didn't notice the second underscore be replaced as well. Oops. Thank you for pointing it out. I would go for stema's approach then, otherwise, mine at best can be fixed by adding a space in the char class and replacing multiple times like `(=[A-Za-z\s]*)_`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't check with a lookbehind assertion if there is a "=" on the left (You would need a variable length pattern inside). You could, under the assumption there is in every row a "=" char, check if there is not a "=" following.

Find `_(?!.*=)`

Replace with a space.

This expression matches an underscore only if there is not a "=" following in the same row. `(?!.*=)` is called a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This assertion is true, if it does not find the pattern inside.